# User authentication via JWT token in NATS WebSocket

Tags: authentication, websocket, jwt, nats.io

I have authorization service that giving JWT tokens with HS256 encryption (by hmac secret key). I want to configure NATS WebSocket for authenticate users via this tokens.

I have tried NATS resolver with URL but it only tried to get accounts in my case and doesn't anything else.

NATS test config:

```js
websocket {
    port: 8085
    no_tls: true
}

resolver: url(http://nats-auth-checker/jwt/v1/accounts/)
```

How to configure users authentication via external JWT tokens in NATS WebSocket?
And I have doubts: is it a normal practice to use NATS as WebSocket gateway for frontend?

Comment: for your second question, AFAIK websockets are there for convenience going through firewalls, but I see a lot of people interested in using it from the browser. I'd be interested to see it working as well.

Comment: Probably you right about firewall bypass usage. Nats websockets works well if you are using predefined token or users from config but I have no idea how to configure nats for decentralized authentication without storing userdata in the config.

I read about auth_callout but it seems like resolver with url.